# Uv map messed up, textures and uv map do not match

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders

i've extracted a model from a game because i'm creating a mod, i've already made the textures but for some ideas i wanted to modify the meshes BUT, whenever i try to put texture on it, texture are messed up and second, uv map is messed up too, i would like to understand if i m making a mistake or not,

texture in shader editor is color to color, alpha to alpha

when i unwrap in the uv editor all the vertices are fit incorrectly (Img 04) as you can see the mask doesn't fit the texture, the same goes for the shell, i.e. therefore i cannot put the texture correctly

hope to find someone that show me the right way cuz i m not understanding where is my mistake... i want only to understand where i do wrong,

i can give more information if you need, i think i explained everything to help me out, follows the screens, thx to everyone.

**Texture messed up**

[image: Texture messed up]

**UV Map messed up**

[image: UV Map messed up]

**Shader Editor**

[image: Shader Editor]

**UV Map unfitted**

[image: UV Map unfitted]

[image]

Comment: it's not clear, you've unwrapped your character, given him a texture that works fine, then reworked the topology, then re-unwrapped?

Comment: Whoa thx, i explain everything, i ve extracted the model, i imported in blender the ,rip files, then i linked the texture via the shader editor, i didn't changed yet the topology, i ve only worked on the original one to match the textures, nothing else, texture and uvmap of the model just extracted do not fits, that s the major issue, the same goes if i work with .obj files,i've both so if can be useful to solve i can work with the objs thx to everyone

Comment: cool, thx Vklidu, i think i can share it now, this is packed with textures, shader, about the uv map i tried today too to fix but few things, looking at the shell you can see it s different, nope size is about 1.7 Mb no problem at all [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=MaBWYBsN" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/MaBWYBsN/)

Comment: ah sorry i thought i did, my bad, i will upload a new one, now the file has been packed, about your question, from .CPK original format file from the game, i extracted with ninja ripper, in format .RIP, and from those files i started working with blender, btw the data in my files are the same .RIP files extracted, i didn't make any change, therefore you are working with the original ones, thx a lot Vklidu [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=87q6b3y7" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/87q6b3y7/)

Comment: Hi there Vklidu, the "mess" comes out once i want to add the texture to the mesh, i think is a blender related matter if the texture do not fit the meshes, i m asking, ah yeah is there something about fixing the uvmap using softwares like Photoshop then re-add the texture in blender, could be my case? could it be useful? i heard about this generic fix for any case not because could be related to my case, thx a lot

Comment: Sorry this discussion is not moving forward. Sure, you get the mess when you add texture in blender, but this mess comes from wrong UVmap that came with model (if you didnt unwrap). UV doesn't match the texture, that is not a fault of blender. So there has to be another texture that match this UV or the UV was for some reason regenerated somewhere in the process of conversion (NinjaRipper or RIP). Photoshop can handle UV for 3D, but I don't thing it has better tools than blender).

Comment: The only way to unwrap UV that will match this texture is to use the same unwrap algorithm used for source. BTW UV on your two screens are different and also UV in provided blend is different so there was some manipulation. The last think I can try ... share your RIP file. I highly recommend to edit your Q, delete all unnecessary and add info about source format NinjaRipper app, .RIP conversion and share RIP file... and delete all comments here I will delete mine (if you want to attract others to help with your issue).

Comment: Hi there Vklidu, thanks for everything so far, the .RIP files are part of the entire mesh, so sharing it will be having an arm or the head and nothing more than that, i can share them no problem, just one thing what kind of info about the source format of ninja ripper do you mean? To sharing the .RIP file i can always use blend-exchange since is the the uploader used here or i need to use another hoster? Thx a lot!